# MVC C# custom Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a `Controller` called `api`, the following

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "api",
  url: "api/",
  defaults: new { controller = "api" }
);
```

inside the controller I have an action as follows

```
[Route("fleet/{id:guid}/selectedfleet")]
public ActionResult selectedfleet(Guid id)
{
    return null;
}
```

the `return null` is just to test this out, I'm trying to get a breakpoint on it
but i am getting url not found, when trying to access something like `http://localhost:50593/api/fleet/2df3893d-c406-48fe-8443-1622ddc51af2/selectedfleet`

Comment: Your route definition does not have `api` in it. Try `http://localhost:50593/fleet/2df3893d-c406-48fe-8443-1622ddc51af2/selectedfleet`

Comment: @Shyju i had tried including like `[Route("api/fleet/{id:guid}/selectedfleet")]` but it doesn't work, not even taking the api away from url

Comment: your route config isnt good about  the params {id:guid} i

Comment: @HenriqueYC why is that?

Comment: you have to write config api/{controller}/{action}/{id} where controller is controller name, action is like selectedfleet and id is the value like 2df3893d-c406-48fe-8443-1622ddc51af2 is all you want to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure that if you want to use attribute routing in MVC, that it is enabled.

```
public class RouteConfig {

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); //<--IMPORTANT for attribute routing in MVC

        // Convention-based routing.

        //...other code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

when trying to access something like `http://localhost:50593/api/fleet/2df3893d-c406-48fe-8443-1622ddc51af2/selectedfleet` via attribute routing you need to make sure that the controller has the proper route template defined to match the request.

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class ApiController : Controller {

    //GET api/fleet/2df3893d-c406-48fe-8443-1622ddc51af2/selectedfleet
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("fleet/{id:guid}/selectedfleet")]
    public ActionResult selectedfleet(Guid id) { ... }
}
```

Make sure that your controller and route does not conflict Web API routes if you have it included in the MVC project.

Comment: the problem was indeed the `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` was about to post it, and for some reason if i expect it to be a guid it wont work, i had to change it as if i was recieving a string, which i dont like since i dont want to trigger that action if a proper Guid isnt sent

Comment: @pato.llaguno, Route constraints were added in MVC 5 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/#route-constraints

Comment: @pato.llaguno the above example works when tested. do you get an error message when using the guid route constraint.?

Answer (score 1):

The routing pattern you defined in the `Route` attribute does not include the term `"api"`. So with your current route definition, the below request will work.

```
yourSiteBaseUrl/fleet/2df3893d-c406-48fe-8443-1622ddc‌​51af2/selectedfleet
```

Or you can add the term api in the route definition.

```
public class apiController : Controller
{
    [Route("api/fleet/{id:guid}/selectedfleet")]
    public ActionResult selectedfleet(Guid id)
    {
        return Content(id.ToString());
    }
}
```

OR using `RoutePrefix` attribute on the controller level

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class apiController : Controller
{
    [Route("fleet/{id:guid}/selectedfleet")]
    public ActionResult selectedfleet(Guid id)
    {
        return Content(id.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now it will work for the below url

```
yourSiteBaseUrl/api/fleet/0a5bb04d-4247-4cf6-8f96-2ce49325b5a7/selectedfleet
```

Comment: have the same output, i get `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found` did the RoutePrefix on controller level

Comment: It should work. I just tested it. Are you sure you are passing a valid Guid ? Did you enable Attribute routing in `RegisterRoutes` method of `RouteConfig` class) by calling `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` ?